# incompatible types when assigning to type struct * from struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I can't understand why i get this error : The error is : "incompatible types when assigning to type 'PERSOANA * {aka struct  *}' from type 'PERSOANA {aka struct }' "
   Can you please explain me where is the mistake ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    char name2[20];
    char cnp[15]; 

} PERSON;

PERSON read_array(int n);

int main()
{
    int n;
    printf("n = ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    PERSON *v;
    v = read_array(n); //here i get the error

    return 0;
}

PERSON read_array(int n) {
    PERSON *v;
    v = malloc(n * sizeof(PERSON));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("name=");
        gets(v[i].name);
        //more instr
    }
    return v; // and also here
}
```

Comment: You try to return a pointer to a struct when you declared to return a struct.

Comment: `PERSON *read_array(int n)` should be the correct syntax.

Comment: Please quote the error message in full and verbatim. It is unlikely that what you quoted is actually the exact and full message.

Comment: Now it works, thx a lot mate !:)

Comment: type of v is PERSON* and return type of the function prototype is PERSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can't understand why i get this error : Incompatible types when assigning to type PERSON from type PERSON.

I am reasonably confident that you **do not** get that error, but if you actually do then you should switch to a better compiler.  I speculate that the error you get is instead

```
Incompatible types when assigning to type PERSON * from type PERSON
```

, because that's in fact what you are trying to do, given your declaration of function `read_array()`.

From implementation and use, it appears that you want that function to return a pointer to a structure rather than a copy of the structure.  That would be

```
PERSON *read_array(int n);
```

... and the same in the function definition.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding, i redited my question, that's the error i've got :) Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Return a pointer to `PERSON`, not the object `PERSON`.

```
// PERSON read_array(int n);
PERSON *read_array(int n);
//     ^

// PERSON read_array(int n) {
//     v
PERSON *read_array(int n) {
```